# I want the current resource processed by MultiResourceItemReader available in beforeStep method

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is there any way to make the **currentResource** processed by **MultiResourceItemReader** to make it available in the **beforeStep** method.Kindly provide me a **working code sample.** I tried injected multiresourcereader reference in to **stepexecutionlistener** , but the spring cglib  only accepts an interface type to be injected ,i dont know whether to use **ItemReader** or **ItemStream** interface.

Comment: I suggest you to carefully set the tags related to your question to get a wider audience. I don't know what is the theme/application/whatever you are talking about, but I am sure it is not a Windows Batch file (that is the target of "batch" tag).

Comment: Your idea to declare `MultiResourceItemReader` reference as `stepexecutionlistener` is not clear to me: for this `MultiResourceItemReader` should implement `StepExecutionListener` interface, and then `beforeStep()` *in* `MultiResourceItemReader` will be called before the step execution.

Answer (score 4):

The `MultiResourceItemReader` [now has](http://angelborroy.wordpress.com/2009/05/15/spring-batch-2-0-current-resource-of-a-multiresourceitemreader/) a method `getCurrentResource()` that returns the current `Resource`.

Answer (score 1):

- Retrieving of `currentResource` from `MultiResourceItemReader` is not possible at the moment. If you need this API enhancement, create one in [Spring Batch JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH).
- Even if there is a getter for `currentResource`, it's value is not valid in `beforeStep()`. It is valid between `open()` and `close()`.

Comment: :Thanks. I saw the source, there is no provision for this.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible, if you use a [Partition Step](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) and the [Binding Input Data to Steps](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#bindingInputDataToSteps) concept

simple code example, with concurrency limit 1 to imitate "serial" processing:

```
<bean name="businessStep:master" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="stepExecutionSplitter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.SimpleStepExecutionSplitter">
            <constructor-arg ref="jobRepository"/>
            <constructor-arg ref="concreteBusinessStep"/>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.spring...MultiResourcePartitioner" scope="step">
                    <property name="resources" value="#{jobParameters['input.file.pattern']}"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property> 
    <property name="partitionHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler">
            <property name="taskExecutor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
                    <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="1" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="step" ref="concreteBusinessStep"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="whateverClass" class="..." scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}" />
</bean>
```

example step configuration:

```
<job id="renameFilesPartitionJob">        
    <step id="businessStep" 
          parent="businessStep:master" />
</job>

<step id="concreteBusinessStep">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="itemReader" 
               writer="itemWriter" 
               commit-interval="5" />
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

potential drawbacks:

- distinct steps for each file instead of one step
- more complicated configuration

Answer (score 0):

Using the **getCurrentResource()** method from **MultiResourceItemReader**, update the stepExecution. Example code as below

```
private StepExecution stepExecution;

@Override
public Resource getCurrentResource() {
    this.stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("FILE_NAME", super.getCurrentResource().getFilename());
    return super.getCurrentResource();
}

@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the item you are reading implement ResourceAware, the current resource is set as it is read

```
public class MyItem implements ResourceAware {

    private Resource resource;
    //others

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public Resource getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

}
```

and in your reader, processor or writer

```
myItem.getResource()
```

will return the resource it was loaded from